How to solve error spawn einval in nodejs
I want to install the node package manager for my Twitter scraping application but I'm getting this error. I've tried several things like downgrading the Node version, disabling Windows Defender System, running PowerShell as an administrator, and so on.
Here's the Error:
npm warn deprecated @types/winston@2.4.4: This is a stub types definition. winston provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm warn deprecated @types/helmet@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. helmet provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm warn deprecated date-format@1.2.0: 1.x is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 4.x or higher.
npm warn deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm error code 1
npm error path D:\Bot\MesinTempur\node_modules\ffi-napi
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm error node:internal/child_process:414
npm error     throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
npm error     ^
npm error
npm error Error: spawn EINVAL
npm error     at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:414:11)
npm error     at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
npm error     at build (D:\Bot\MesinTempur\node_modules\node-gyp-build\bin.js:30:8)
npm error     at preinstall (D:\Bot\MesinTempur\node_modules\node-gyp-build\bin.js:39:32)
npm error     at D:\Bot\MesinTempur\node_modules\node-gyp-build\bin.js:11:7
npm error     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
npm error     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm error     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm error     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
npm error     at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28) {
npm error   errno: -4071,
npm error   code: 'EINVAL',
npm error   syscall: 'spawn'
npm error }
npm error
npm error Node.js v18.20.4


What command did you run in the terminal? Please post your package.json content aswell. Do you use any packages that depend on building/node-gyp(-build)? Is your pc setup correctly to handle building with node-gyp?

I just reset my windows (fresh), and still meet the same problem. i run npm i in the command. heres the package :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGZlE_zpGplby7XnByFeBn9sKUC1mvsL/view?usp=sharing

I think this issue related this Security Releases: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/april-2024-security-releases-2
You can downgrade to node 16 and install again to solve it.

I Am using cheerio, it must be node >= 18.x.x

node 16 is EOL. Terrible advice.
